# Characterization of the Poisson distribution

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-distribution, stochastic-analysis, poissons-equation

Let $Z$ be a $[0, \infty)$-valued random variable satisfying $\lambda E[g(Z+1)] = E[Zg(Z)]$ for all indicator functions $g$ of Borel subsets of $[0, \infty)$.

Prove that $\mathcal{L}(Z) = Poisson(\lambda)$.

Hint: Consider  $1_{(n,n+1)}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

Proof:

Let $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$ and g = 1_{(n,n+1)}, then holds:
\begin{align*}
\lambda E[g(Z+1)] = \lambda P[Z+1 \in (n,n+1)] = \lambda (P[Z+1 = n+1] - P[Z+1 = n]) = \lambda P[Z = n] - \lambda P[Z = n-1]).
\end{align*}
But what is
\begin{align*}
E[Zg(Z)] = E[Z \cdot 1_{(n,n+1)}(Z)] = ?
\end{align*}

Have I got everything right so far? If so, how should I proceed now?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just choose $g=\mathbf{1}_{\{n\}}$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$. Set $a_n=P(Z=n)$ you get the recursive equation
$$a_{n-1}=\frac{n}{\lambda}a_n$$
And if you plug in $a_n=\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}e^{-\lambda}$ you're done.

Answer (score 1):

The assertion $$P[Z+1\in(n,n+1)]=P[Z+1=n+1]-P[Z+1=n]\tag1$$ isn't quite correct. To assert the RHS of (1) you would need to prove that $Z$ takes only integer values, and also you would need $(n,n+1]$ on the LHS instead of $(n,n+1)$.

Hint: You should first show that $Z$ takes only integer values. Consider the case $n=0$ first, so try $g:=I_{(0,1)}$ in the identity $\lambda E[g(Z+1)]=E[Zg(Z)]$. You'll get
$$\lambda P(0<Z+1<1) = E[ZI_{(0,1)}(Z)].$$
The LHS equals zero because the variable $Z$ is $[0,\infty)$-valued. The RHS is the expectation of a non-negative random variable, hence $ZI_{(0,1)}(Z)$ equals zero almost surely. Explain why this implies $P[Z\in(0,1)]=0$. Continue in this way to prove that $P[Z\in(n,n+1)]=0$ for every $n=1,2,\ldots$.

Second hint: After you've proved that $Z$ takes only values $0, 1, 2,\ldots$, you can assert (1), using $(n,n+1]$ instead of $(n, n+1)$ on the LHS. If you know $Z$ is integer-valued, then $E[Z\cdot I_{(n,n+1]}(Z)] = (n+1) P(Z=n+1)$.